# How to sample 10% of the data from a table?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

How can I return 10% of the rows from a table in Snowflake. For example, how can I return the 10th, 20th, 30th row based after sorting a table.

Answer (score 5):

Using QUALIFY and modulo division:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY some_column) % 10 = 0;
```

Comment: (+1) Nice Lukasz ! I didn't know about `QUALIFY` - is it just syntactic sugar to avoid the subquery approach in my answer, or is there more going on under the hood (and if so is it more efficient ?)

Comment: @RobertLong QAULIFY is a nice to way to easily filter on windowed function without needing to nest queries. It improves readability of the code and it is really handy :)

Comment: Syntactic sugar then ?!

Comment: @RobertLong It would rather think about QAULIFY clause as natural extension. It is the same for windowed functions as HAVING is for GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making use of modulo arithmetic and the ROW_NUMBER window function:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CC_REC_END_DATE) as rownum
  FROM "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."CALL_CENTER"
) t
WHERE t.rownum % 10 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, I think you're looking for `SAMPLE`.

From the [Snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/sample.html):
Fraction-based Row Sampling - Return a sample of a table in which each row has a 10% probability of being included in the sample:

```
select * from testtable sample (10);
```

Comment: That would be a random sample. I think the OP wants a deterministic sample (10th, 20th, 30th row, etc)